# Oracle performance - disabling FKs to make DELETE statement work faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-delete

When deleting from a large table in Oracle - let's call it table X - does it make sense to disable table X's FKs that do not have ON DELETE CASCADE?  I'm not referring to disabling FKs on other tables that link to table X, but just disabling FKs on table X to improve the performance of the DELETE statements.

I'm making the indexes on table X unusable, but the DELETE still takes a while.

I think that those FKs don't matter to the performance of the DELETE statement since we're just deleting, and not inserting or updating, so the FKs don't need to be checked. What do you think?

Comment: It is possible that the mere existence of the foreign keys (which have corresponding indexes) causes the delete to use the wrong index. Can you write the DELETE in a way that will use the correct index, say with a hint or a modification of your where clause?

Comment: More than likely it's the FKs pointing /to/ table X that cause any delay, or possibly the volume of data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I didn't have to disable those FKs before the archive process starts and enable them when the process ends. But instead, in order to improve performance of the DELETE statements, we had to drop indexes before the archive process starts and recreate them after the archive process finishes. We also committed more often.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a really bad idea. No matter what you do, you'll have a period where referential integrity is not enforced on your database. Then you go to put the FKs back in place and, oops, someone has inserted an invalid row.

Furthermore, `ALTER TABLE` is a DDL statement, so executing it will commit any work up to that point. You'll lose the ability to rollback if something goes wrong elsewhere in your transaction.

Can you look through the explain plan to see why your `DELETE` statement is taking so long?

Comment: I'm talking about an database archiving process that will run while all users are locked out, so no worries for having someone inserting an invalid row while FKs are disabled. Also the ALTER TABLE will happen at the beginning of the archive job when there is nothing to commit. The explain plan is showing usage of indexes and everything looks normal. I think the main problem here is the volume of the table and the number of indexes on it (i can make only some of them unusable)

Comment: I think kurosch makes a good point: FKs pointing to your table still need to be validated when you do the delete, to make sure you're not deleting a child record. Maybe that's the problem?